# Package manager does not see sql server and does not create migrations. What is the solution?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework, sql-server-2014

I want to connect visual studio 2019 with sql server 2014 studio and create migrations.Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString'); I get the error I couldn't find a solution. Can you help?
note: I don't use ado.net in my application

---

```
appsettings.json


{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LibraryConnection": "DESKTOP-NHG0GU1\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library_Dev;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
Context.cs


using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MusicStoreRazor.UI.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreListContext:DbContext
    {
        public MusicStoreListContext(DbContextOptions<MusicStoreListContext> options):base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Music> Musics { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the connection string mapping in startup.cs as you are not mapping it in the Dbcontext itself.